# Create new column from two column with logic in R?

Tags: r

Looking for other way than ifelse.

How to create NewColumn like this:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried thus far?

Comment: Still exploring.

Comment: Please read [how to post a good SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and substantially edit your post to follow those guidelines.

Comment: Tired this. all$NewColumn<-ifelse(all$NewColumn %in% c('2452','5224'), '2424',
                                ifelse(all$NewColumn %in% c('3942','4239'), '3942',
                                       ifelse(all$NewColumn %in% c('4880','8048'), '4880',"Other")))

Comment: My assumption would be that you always need the lower number first, but you didn't mention it, nor did you mention anything about the rules. And your example code (which should be in the question and not in comments) has hardcoded values not mentioned anywhere

Comment: Do you always only have two columns? You just need to `sort` before using `paste`.

Comment: all$NewColumn<-ifelse(all$NewColumn %in% c('2452','5224'), '2424',
                                ifelse(all$NewColumn %in% c('3942','4239'), '3942',
                                       ifelse(all$NewColumn %in% c('4880','8048'), '4880',"Other")))

Comment: Maybe try

`library(tidyverse)`

`all %>% mutate(NewColumn = if_else(Column1 < Column2, paste(Column1, Column2, sep = ""), paste(Column2, Column1, sep = "")))`

Answer (score 1):

As displayed in your picture, you want to `paste` together two columns. Assuming your dataframe is called `df`, you can do:

```
 df$NewColumn <- paste(df$Column2,"",df$Column1)
```

Which will get you the outcome in the picture.

Comment: paste will only join to columns, Please check the photo, to understand the logic i am looking for.

Comment: 12 ,11 becomes 1211 and 11,12 becomes 1211 or vise versa

Comment: Tired below logic, but to many combination so, ifelse query will be very long, so looking for other way out. all$NewColumn<-ifelse(all$NewColumn %in% c('2452','5224'), '2424',
                                ifelse(all$NewColumn %in% c('3942','4239'), '3942',
                                       ifelse(all$NewColumn %in% c('4880','8048'), '4880',"Other")))